# What does the term data classes only mean?

Tags: uml

I have been told to create an analysis diagram but it states that only date classes should be added. I thought that is what you use anyway, or am I thinking about this wrongly

"The models include a domain/analysis class diagram (which contains data classes only)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't ever use this terminology but my guess is that the instructor/manager wants your model to contain only the classes that will be later on implemented in the database (i.e. those that represent the concepts that you´ll need to store information about). To me this set coincides with what I´d refer to as  domain classes but maybe your instructor has a different interpretation